# Spring Jackson is escaping backslash

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I have a Spring Boot application that I'm using `@RestController` to return a String.  I'm using a Velocity template to create the string and the returned String after the velocity merge remains unchanged.The String contains html code, and a zip pattern like:

```
<input required type='tel' value='' title='zip' pattern='\d{5}' name='zip' />
```

The JSON response from the controller is escaping the backslash so it appears like:

```
<input required type='tel' value='' title='zip' pattern='\\d{5}' name='zip' />
```

Is there a way to configure Jackson so it doesn't do the additional escape?

Comment: Don't use a `@RestController` for this, let Spring resolve and render the view instead.

Comment: I need this to be returned as JSON.

Comment: It's HTML... How do you see that as JSON?

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the escaping when it's returned as JSON?